# Protect post request for manipulating database

Tags: php, reactjs, ajax, database, rest

I am working on a react app which should be part of the admin area of a WooCommerce shop. To have more freedom in my react app a created some ajax endpoints which call functions that manipulate the database:

- Read database table
- Insert row
- Update row

Since it's a react app everyone who accesses the JS code is able to see that the JS function makes a post request. This is obviously very unsafe and can be abused. To avoid this I have integrated the following security methods:

- The functions are only able to manipulate my custom tables
- Cross-origin http requests are forbidden
- The react app is only visible in admin area of WooCommerce
- I check with Wordpress if the user is an admin

**JS function**

```
const insertDb = async (table, columns, values) => {
    const data = {
        action: 'insertDb',
        table: table,
        columns: columns,
        values: values
    }

    const rsp = await axios.post("/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", qs.stringify(data))
    return rsp.data
}
```

**PHP function**

```
function insertDb($table, $columns, $values) {
    if (current_user_can('administrator') && substr($table, 0, 6) === "mytable") {
        global $wpdb;
        $table = $wpdb->prefix . $table;
        $values = str_replace("\\", "", $values);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($columns) VALUES ($values);";
        $wpdb->query($sql);
        $id = $wpdb->insert_id;

        return $id;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is this still unsafe? How am I able to improve it? What's the best practice?

Thank you!!

Comment: why don't use validation user in php and not in js, so `if($user==admin){do}else{reject}`?

Comment: Thanks. Good point! I removed the secret and adjusted the PHP function. But that doesn't change anything to the security level.

Comment: You should take a look at GraphQL. This is essentially what it does.

Comment: @Cfreak Slapping a GraphQL implementation on a Wordpress thing is just a silly proposition. Besides, GraphQL doesn't inherently add any security.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better to define the mutations you want to allow in the server code, rather than allow the client, if logged in with suitable privileges, to insert arbitrary rows into your database.

At the very least:

- add an allowlist for `$table` to check whether it's a table that's supposed to be updated

Preferably:

- change the payload to e.g. JSON so you'll get richer types, and then
- parse `$columns` from an array of strings
- parse `$values` from an array and then use [prepared queries and placeholders](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#protect-queries-against-sql-injection-attacks).

Even more preferably, as said:

- limit the queries to a known-good set (e.g. "add page with title and text", "add something else") – this way you'll basically end up with something of a (REST) API